# will P copy mcache to G stack when switch to new G?

Tags: go, goroutine

In Go's GMP (goroutine, system thread, context) model, a goroutine may produce many objects and put them in P (heap memory?), will all data on P copied to G's stack when it's parked? If so, G's stack may grow very large, which makes the design of P seems meaningless, but if not, how does the scheduler solve the problem that multi G's data store in P in the same time? And it's impossible if G wants to execute on another P.
my question is

1. will all data copy to G' stack when g is parked?
2. why not just put all data on G when executing G?

Comment: thanks for your comment, I will add this to my question, hope for deeper explanation about my question

Comment: Note that your question makes not much sense as this is not specified by the language and any compiler (for each architecture and each version) might do it completely differently. Well, gc and gcc use the same mechanism while targeting amd and arm on any OS. And probably for WASM too but I'm unsure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a fundamental misunderstanding in your question: `mcache` is **not** a placeholder for the stack, it's a short-cut for small allocations on the heap. It holds pre-allocated blocks of memory that can be handed out to a particular goroutine, avoiding locking.

The compiler decides whether a particular variable must be allocated on the heap. Once it does, this will **never be copied back to the stack**.

The question is now how to allocate memory from the heap as efficiently as possible. This is where `mcache`, `mcentral`, and `mheap` come in.

- `mcache` is a list of pre-allocated blocks of various sizes, with one `mcache` per processor **P**. Since **P** runs a single goroutine **G** at a time, allocations from `mcache` do not need to lock.
- If `mcache` runs out of pre-allocated blocks, more are requested from `mcentral` which is shared across **P**s.
- If `mcentral` runs out, more blocks are requested from `mheap` which may in turn request more memory from the OS.
- If the requested blocks are large enough, they are directly requested from `mheap`.

The point of all this is to avoid locking during small memory allocations. But all sections of memory obtained from `mcache`, `mcentral` and `mheap` are part of **the heap**, they can be used by **G** no matter which **P** it is running on, and they must be garbage collected when no longer in use.

You can find a lot more details about **heap** memory allocation in the following:

- [Go: Memory Management and Allocation](https://medium.com/a-journey-with-go/go-memory-management-and-allocation-a7396d430f44)
- [A visual guide to Go Memory Allocator from scratch](https://blog.learngoprogramming.com/a-visual-guide-to-golang-memory-allocator-from-ground-up-e132258453ed)
- [Memory Management in Golang](https://www.timqi.com/2020/06/11/golang-memory-management/)

Comment: thanks for your answer, I am studying these posts.  " they can be used by G no matter which P it is running on" left a question, if a goroutine left some data on a mcache and now it go to another P, if it wants to write the old data,  will  it be allocated to the current mcache?

Comment: `mcache` is not "data storage", it's just a record of some available memory blocks. An entry in a given **P**'s `mcache` will be marked as allocated and given to the goroutine. But there is nothing that ties this part of the memory to a given **P**, it's just accounting.